# Magento 2 online refund for custom payment method

Tags: magento2, module, custom, payment-gateway, refund

I am developing a Magento 2 custom payment module for one of my  clients, yet I am now totally blocked in finding a way to process an online refund for any of the created orders. I can't locate the Online refund button and all I found was the offline refund button, so I tried to trigger the refund by adding canRefund throw the config.xml file and add it in the payment module but there is something still missing so if any one can help i will be appreciated?

config.xml

```
<active>1</active>
<can_refund>1</can_refund>
<can_capture>1</can_capture>
```

payment.php

```
    namespace magento\payment\Model;
    
    
    class Payment extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
    {
    
        protected $_isInitializeNeeded      = false;
        protected $redirect_uri;
        protected $_code = "mycode";
        protected $_canOrder = true;
        protected $_isGateway = true;
        protected $_canCapture = true;
        protected $_canCapturePartial = true;
        protected $_canRefund = true;
    
    
    
        public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {
           return \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                                ->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface')->getUrl("mycode/redirect");
       }
       public function refund(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
       {
          // some code

          return ;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked hard on this issue.
In Magento, refunds work with Sales Invoices, not Order.

1. Make sure the sales invoice is created correctly.
   To make sure the invoice is correct, check the amount and that it includes the order items.
   If there is no problem with your invoice, you will see Credit Memo button. (a screen like this: https://i.snipboard.io/ej8nsG.jpg)
2. Confirm that there is a `<can_refund>1</can_refund>` tag in the module's config.xml.
3. Check that the module has a refund method. It is located under the class you derived with `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\xx`.

Example:

```
public function refund( \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount )
{
 $transactionId = $payment->getParentTransactionId();
 // your api requests
 $request = $this->refundAction();
 if($request->error)
 {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception( __( 'Payment refunding error.' ) );
 }
 return $this;  
}
```

If all is OK, the "Refund" button should look in Credit Memo creating: https://i.snipboard.io/6M28uo.jpg